# Mysql database trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I'm still new in msyql database trigger. I would like to ask about my lines:

```
CREATE TRIGGER secure_dml3
BEFORE DELETE ON t_pembelian
BEGIN
 IF (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'DY') IN ('SUN')) OR
 (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI') NOT BETWEEN '09.45' AND '20.30')
    THEN
    IF DELETING THEN
    CALL RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20502,'Perubahan pada data hanya dapat dilakukan hanya pada jam kerja.');
 END IF; 
 END IF; 
END
```

Mysql always say that there is an error near

> 'BEGIN IF (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'DY') IN ('SUN')) OR (SELECT
>   TO_CHAR (SYSD' at line 3.

I really need your help. Thank you

Comment: First thing you are missing the delimiter. So add the following at the beginning `delimiter //` and the last `END` should be as `END //` Next there is no function `TO_CHAR` in mysql and looks like you have copied some oracle trigger. And in mysql `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is not available and its called `SIGNAL`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to ask again, to_char should be replace by what syntax? And I only need to change raise_application_error with signal?

Comment: Checkout mysql docs for `date_format` and `SIGNAL` for raising the error from trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing oracle with MySql. In MySql doesn't exist `TO_CHAR` you may use `DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE,'DY')`